# Onclick function not working with custom popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created custom popup to show my records.

I am using CodeIgniter, I am fetching records from database and display on the view page which is working.

Now I have records in the view page like this

```
EmpName EMPID Mobile No.  Status    Action

xyz     122   0012141010  Pending   view archive

mnb     123   0124541021  Pending   view archive

poiu    124   0000000000  Approved  view archive
```

What I am doing is, When user click on `" pending"`  then it will ask for confirmation popup `"Are you sure want to continue?"` If the user clicks on `"Later"` button then the popup will close. It will not take any action. There is no issue till now.

Now let's talk about `Sure` button. Sure button not taking any action. I don't understand why it's not calling the submit action. Even it's not working on the archive.

> Note: I don't want to use `confirm()` or any `alert()` popup

**View page**

```
<div class="white_bg pad0 m_b_20">
  <div class="emp_list">
    <div class=" ">
      <?php if (!empty($get_emp_records)) {?>
      <table cellspacing="0" id="tableData">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="" width="3%"> <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />
            </th>
            <th class="" width="15%"> EmpName </th>
            <th class="" width="7%"> EMP ID</th>
            <th class="" width="11%"> Mobile No. </th>
            <th class="" width="13%"> Status </th>
            <th class="" width="23%"> Action </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php  
            foreach ($get_emp_records as $row)  
            { $encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->id));//encrpt the id 
        ?>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="3%"><input type="checkbox" name="crm" class="crm_select" value="0" /></td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row->firstname;  echo $row->lastname;?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row->employee_id;?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row->mobileno;?>
            </td>
            <?php if ($row->is_approved == 1): ?>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_icon approved">Approved</a></td>
            <?php else: ?>
            <td>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_icon pending" onclick="approve(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>"> <span>Pending</span></a>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Employee_control/get_employee_view?key='.$encryption_id)?>" class="table_icon view">View</a>

              <a href="<?php echo site_url('Employee_control/employee_archive?key='.$encryption_id)?>" class="table_icon archive">Archive</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!--conformation popup-->
          <div class="confirmation_alert" id="popup-<?=$row->id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <div class="opacity"></div>
            <div class="profile_content">
              <div class="profile_header clearfix">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close_popup " onclick="closePopup(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>"> x </a>
                <div class="profile_name_pic"> Confirmation!!! </div>
                <div class="profile_header_right">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="profile_body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="leave_reason">
                      <h3>Are you sure want to continue?</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="profile_footer clearfix">
                <button type="submit" class="btn_default submit_btn" id="confirm">Sure</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn_default edit_btn" onclick="closePopup(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>">Later</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
      <?php }else{echo "No record found";}?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

function approve(obj) {
  var id = $(obj).data('id');
  $("#popup-" + id).show();
  var el = document.getElementById("confirm");
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
      //alert("clicked");
      window.location = url + "Employee_control/approved_user?key=" + id;
    });
  }
  return false;
}

function closePopup(obj) {
  var id = $(obj).data('id');
  $("#popup-" + id).hide();
};
```

Comment: you must use a bootstrap modal.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin, thanks for the reply. Any other solution?

Comment: you must say how can I use modal for configuration?

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin, Sorry I can't get you. I am not using the bootstrap modal. I have created my own with style and I have to make an event on button click

Comment: its easy to use bootstrap modal. you can create your own modal.

Comment: i create a answer for you.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin, I really appreciate your efforts but I can't use it bootstrap. that's the reason I created my own modal.

Comment: only you can use javascript code or idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Since your r not submitting any form you should change your button type from `submit` to `button` like this :

```
<div class="profile_footer clearfix"> 
     <button type="button" class="btn_default submit_btn" id="confirm">Sure</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn_default edit_btn" onclick="closePopup(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>">Later</button>
</div>
```

Your js code should be like this :

```
var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
function approve(obj) 
{ 
    var id = $(obj).data('id'); 
    $("#popup-"+id).show(); 
    $('.submit_btn').on('click',function(e) {
        alert('hi i am working');
        window.location = url+"Employee_control/approved_user?key="+id;
    e.preventDefault();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Give me some time to implement this

Comment: It's not taking any action after click on submit. Is it working from your side?

Comment: NO, there is no error showing in the console. It's empty

Comment: i have edited my answer make sure u r using edited answer

Comment: Oh! wait I am checking again.

Comment: Yes, I updated your answer with my code. I think there is little bit issue. I added the console.log(id); before the #confirm script. I am getting the id value correct but when I am adding the console.log(id); inside #confirm script then I am not getting it. even alert also not working.

Comment: is ur popup appears on click?

Comment: I removed e.preventDefault(); but nothing is happing. Yes After clicking on the approve button I am getting the popup but submit button is not working

Comment: did u change button type from `submit` to `button`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174104/discussion-between-user9437856-and-pradeep).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var modalConfirm = function(callback){
    $(".btn-confirm").on("click", function(){
   $("#mi-modal").modal('show');
    });
    $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function(){
   callback(true);
   $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
    
    $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function(){
   callback(false);
   $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
  };
  modalConfirm(function(confirm){
    if(confirm){
     alert('delete works fine');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' value="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-confirm">

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="mi-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Do you want to delete?</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="modal-btn-si"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Yes</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no"><i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i> No</button>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate it your answer but I cant you bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

Hope it will work, try adding click event on `id`of submit

try using

```
$('#confirm').click(function()
{
  // do tricks
});
```